# ¿Cómo hago para que Visual Studio Code no me formatee todo el texto en la misma línea en HTML?

Tags: html5, vscode, procesamiento-de-texto

Si pongo

```
hola
que
tal
```

Al guardar el archivo me lo cambia automáticamente a

`hola que tal`

Y yo quiero las distinas líneas. No todo seguido.

He quitado de la configuración "Format On Save" y sigue igual. No sé que es.

Comment: Prueba poniendo etiquetas. Si es html, por defecto todo debe estar en una linea mientras sea solo texto sin etiquetas. (Tampo es que se a muy conocedor). Con <br> deberias tener el resultado deseado (el visual code, no en el navegador)

Comment: @Angel si, eso ya lo se, pero tengo que andar copiando y pegando muchísimo texto, y si tengo que poner <br> para que quede igual, me puedo morir antes de terminarlo.

Comment: Guarda como txt

Comment: Copia y pega tu código para poder ayudarte mejor,que lenguaje de programación estas usando?.

Comment: @arturosoga lo pone en el titulo... html. Pero el código da igual, es cosa de la configuracion de vscode...

Comment: @Angel es para una página, ha de ser html...

Comment: ok, checa la respuesta que puse.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar agregando estilos:

```html
<div style="white-space: pre">
  hola
  que 
  tal
</div>

<div>
  sin
  el
  estilo
</div>
```

Esto respetara tu texto, pero no impedira que visual code lo formatee.

Puedes ver [mas acerca de esto aqui](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-break-line-without-using-br-tag-in-html-css/).